# Can I Recover Firefox and Tor Bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, filesystem, tor, migration

I will be going back to Windows, because after months of dealing with Linux, I realized it's not for me. In short, right now Linux won't present the login screen. There are things I want to save before I format this hard drive with Linux installed.

I can explore this hard disk drive with a different OS. I never exported either Tor's or Firefox's bookmarks, so I'm hoping they are lying around somewhere in the Ubuntu Filesystem. Is this the case? I am assuming I can just take the Tor bundle directory with me, use it in a Linux virtual machine, and export it's bookmarks, but what about Firefox? Can I just take it's directory with me someplace else? If so, where is Firefox installed?

Comment: If you don't see the graphical login screen, you might be facing some problems with the drivers used for your graphic card. Trying another one might be a solution. In some very rare cases, I replaced the graphic card which was badly supported by another cheap one very well supported...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you just have to copy the folder "firefox" and all its content.
This folder is located in the hidden folder ".mozilla" of your personal folder (/home/username/).

On another operating system (Linux, Mac or Windows), you just have to launch Mozilla Firefox once. Then close it and copy the profile folder (xxxxxx.default) from the "firefox" backup folder in the corresponding "firefox" folder for your platform. After that, I recommend you to edit "profiles.ini" and replace the "Path" value by the name of the profile folder copied instead of overwriting that file with the one from the backup.

On Windows 7/8/8.1, you'll find "firefox" folder (containing profiles) in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\".

That's what I use very often to do the contrary (migrating from Windows or Mac to Linux).

P.S.: Please note that you may have to replace add-ons which are designed for Linux by the ones designed for your platform.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this answer a go as soon as I start settings things up again. Add-ons are not a problem since I never used them.

Answer (score 0):

All your firefox settings are there in the hidden ~/.mozilla/firefox directory. There you'll find another directory ending with *.default within which you'll find a directory called "bookmarkbackups" that contains time to time backup of all your bookmarks as *.jason files. You can import a *.jason file in firefox bookmark library.

There is an option to sync all the firefox data...bookmark passwords etc. online. When you sign in to that account on a different device, it will sync back all your firefox data. I hope it will help you in future from data loss.

[image]

Comment: Wish I knew that so I could have configured this when my Linux box worked.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed the point that you cannot log in.

Comment: All your firefox settings are there in the hidden ~/.mozilla directory. There within this you'll also find a directory called "bookmarkbackups" that contains time to time backup of all your bookmarks as *.jason files. Hope that helps.